# Auto load class defined in php c-extension with class name resolution

Tags: php, autoloader

The __autoload method can help to load class in file as bellow.

```
public static function __autoLoad($className)
{
    @include_once str_replace(array('\\', '_'), '/', $className) . '.php';
}

//file: /lib/parent.php
<?php
class Lib_Parent
{
     //...
}

//file: /client/runtime.php
<?php
class Client_Runtime extends Lib_Parent
{
    //...
}
```

The __autoload resolute class to the path to file and include it.
But I have some classes defined in third c-extension, these code cannot execute exactly for it try to include none exist file to load class.

My question is how to load C-extension class using auto load?

Comment: Why should that be possible? If some class has a namespace, load it using the namespace

Comment: My purpose is to write code with ignore to write 'use namespace'.
Updated post to make my question more clear.